# user input reads through dictionary find number of occurrences of a word

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to have the user input a name that I have in a dictionary that is in `row 3`. The program will look through the dictionary in `row 3` to find the word and count how many times the word appears on a separate line.

I also would like to program to find all the zip codes this type of tree is found in and the city that has the greatest number of this type of tree.

**Enter a command**: treeinfo white oak

**Entry**: white oak

```
Total number of such trees: 642
Zip codes in which this tree is found: 10011,11103,11375,10002,10463
Borough containing the largest number of such trees: Bronx, with 432
```

Here is what I have so far, it ask me to enter tree name and nothing happens then it loops as ask me to enter tree name again.

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter
# variables
# Load data into string variable
# file is variable called data
with open('nyc_street_trees.csv','r') as my_file:
     data = my_file.read()

# Create a list of each row
rows = data.split("\n")

# Create a dictionary
tree_type = {}

# Iterate through each row, this prints out each row on a separate line
for row in rows:
    # Split the row into info
    info = row.split(",")

    # Check if the row is the proper length
    if len(info) == 9:
        # separate out the data
        tree_id = info[0]
        tree_dbh = info[1]
        health = info[2]
        spc_common = info[3]
        zipcode = info[4]
        boroname = info[5]
        nta_name = info[6]
        latitude = info[7]
        longitude = info[8]

        # Populate the dictionary
        tree_type[spc_common] = info[3]

        userinput = input('Enter tree species:')

count = 0
for key in tree_type:
    if tree_type[spc_common] == 'userinput':
        count += 1

print(count)

#print(tree_type)
        # prints out the row with tree names
       # print(f'Spc: {spc_common} ')
#print(data)
#print(rows)
  # print(row)
#print(type(rows))
  # print(type(info), info)
```

What i see when I run the program:

```py
Enter tree species:mulberry
Enter tree species:
```

I'm still a beginner so maybe someone can catch what i'm doing wrong here.

I tried to swap

```
with open('nyc_street_trees.csv','r') as my_file:
     data = my_file.read()
```

with

```
inputFile = open("data.txt", "r")
```

I tried

```
count = 0
for key in tree_type:
    if tree_type[spc_common] == 'data':
        count += 1
```

Comment: Your input:  `userinput = input('Enter tree species:')` is indented incorrectly. Because of this indentation, you have it within your `for-loop`. In python, indentation matters.

Comment: Also this line is not doing what you think it does: `if tree_type[spc_common] == 'userinput':` . This code is checking if the variable `tree_type[spc_common]` is equal to the string `"userinput"` but has nothing to do with what the user has entered or the variable that you have named `userinput`.

Comment: Also - this line will not populate the dictionary in the way you anticipate:  `tree_type[spc_common] = info[3]`  - it should be `tree_type['spc_common'] = info[3]`

Comment: Okay, so it should be out side the for loop? and tree_type is supposed to have the userinput iterate through my dictionary and find row 3 which has all the names of the trees. I thought that was what it was supposed to do.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can setup a users input to iterate through a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to import and manipulate data from a CSV is from the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html).

- Import the CSV file into a dataframe
- Extract relevant information from the dataframe

As you have not provided the headers for the CSV, I have used row and column index notation to retrieve the data. I have made the assumption that the columns you used are correct. It would be safer to use the column header names, but the following code should work nonetheless.

- `df.iloc[:,3]` and `df.columns[3]` = refers to the **spc_common** column
- `df.iloc[:,4]` = refers to the **zipcode** column
- `df.iloc[:,5]` and `df.columns[5]` = refers to the **borough** column

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Import the data from CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('nyc_street_trees.csv')

# Get user to enter the tree species
userinput = input("Enter tree species:")

# Find the number of trees of that species
number_of_trees = df.iloc[:,3][df.iloc[:,3] == userinput].count()

# Find the zip codes containing that species
zip_codes = ",".join(map(str, list(set(df.iloc[:,4][df.iloc[:,3] == userinput]))))

# Find the borough containing the most number of trees of that species
borough_with_most_trees = df.iloc[:,[3,5]][df.iloc[:,3] == userinput].groupby(df.columns[5]).count().nlargest(1, columns=(df.columns[3]))

# Display output
print(f"Total number of {userinput} trees: {number_of_trees}")
print(f"Zip codes in which {userinput} trees are found: {zip_codes}")
print(f"Borough containing the largest number of {userinput} trees: {borough_with_most_trees.index[0]}, with {borough_with_most_trees.iloc[0,0]}")
```

Comment: I tried that, the only problem is my python won't upgrade from 2.7 so it won't import pandas.

Comment: From what I have read - there are ways to install pandas on python 2.7

Comment: You are very helpful, Thank you. I've look through tons of YouTube videos to see why it cannot find Pandas Module. 

I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I might just close this thread and try seeing if I can find a solution on Stackoverflow.

I tried your code on another computer which had Pandas and it does work, for some reason it just doesn't work on my MacBook Pro.

It won't find pip, pip3, pip -v, etc

Comment: Try this:  `pip install numpy==1.10.4` then `pip install pandas`. If you already have numpy, then remove it, and install the one I mentioned.

Comment: do you have pip2 ?

Comment: I did pip install numpy==1.10.4 and got the same message.

Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install python-pip
Please ask your administrator, I don't think I have numpy.
I went to https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3111/ and removed python and re downloaded yesterday and got the same message.

Comment: Ok - then I think you will need try resolve that separate issue. on StackOverflow. Once you get over that hurdle, this code will work for you :) Best to uninstall python, and re-install latest version. Make sure you have admin rights. The numpy mentioned above was only for python version 2.7. So do not use that command for python 3.

Comment: I tried pip2 and got the error

Command 'pip2' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install python-pip
Please ask your administrator.

So, I guess I don't have that either, I'll try to Delete Python again and use numpy and see if that works. Thanks a bunch.